# Monthly function generates missing values

Tags: stata

I am attempting to use the `monthly()` function in Stata to convert a set of month-year pairs from string to numeric. The data for this variable appear as follows:

```
rcsbirth
072005
101993
012001
121994
```

I have been able to do this using the `date()` function:

```
generate childbirth = date(rcsbirth,"MY")
```

Next, I use:

```
format childbirth %td
```

Variable `childbirth` now lists as follows for the respective `rcsbirth` dates:

```
 01jul2005
 01oct1993
 01jan2001
 01dec1994
```

When I try to apply this very same process using the `monthly()` function, and formatting using `%tm` instead of `date()` with `%td`, it produces all missing values in the new `childbirth` variable.

Again, I am trying to apply:

```
generate childbirth = monthly(rcsbirth, "MY")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm this problem and cannot explain it.

Here are two ways to get monthly dates in one line from your example data.

```
input str6 rcsbirth
"072005"
"101993"
"012001"
"121994"
end 

generate childbirth = ym(real(substr(rcsbirth,-4,4)), real(substr(rcsbirth, 1, 2)))
generate childbirth2 = mofd(date(rcsbirth, "MY"))
format childbirth* %tm

list

       +--------------------------------+
       | rcsbirth   childb~h   childb~2 |
       |--------------------------------|
    1. |   072005     2005m7     2005m7 |
    2. |   101993    1993m10    1993m10 |
    3. |   012001     2001m1     2001m1 |
    4. |   121994    1994m12    1994m12 |
       +--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The **datetime translation** help file (`help datetime_translation`) states:

> *"...monthly() translates a year and a month number (1-12)..."*

The following thus works:

```
generate wanted = monthly(substr(rcsbirth, 1, 2) + " " + substr(rcsbirth, 3, .), "MY")                                                                                      
format wanted %tm

list

     +--------------------+
     | rcsbirth    wanted |
     |--------------------|
  1. |   072005    2005m7 |
  2. |   101993   1993m10 |
  3. |   012001    2001m1 |
  4. |   121994   1994m12 |
     +--------------------+
```

In other words, the month must be separated by the year with a space, `-` or `/`.